# Jmeter- how to break while controller after getting successful repsonse

Tags: jmeter

I am seeking help on how to break while controller loop when I got successful response.

```
Steps:-
1. I have a while controller where I kept below logic
${__javaScript((${controller} < 5),)}
2. And inside while controller I have created http request which return response.
This request takes some time to give result.if this request is still
running it will return status code 202.. and if this request is completed it will give 200.(I have another API to check this)

So here I dont know when it will get success.
for that after each request I have kept waiting time.
So when I call first time after while loop.. its giving 202(because its still running)
and I will continue this process till 5 times..
So here there is chance I can get 200 success code at 3rd request.
So what I want here is I would like to break the loop after that..I dont want to run till 5 times.

I am using below code to read the response.

if (status_code == "200"){
            AssertionResult.setFailure(false); 
    }
```

So when I get the 200 from response it should stop and get success
and if I dont get 200 from response in all 5 attempts, it should get failed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the API request and configure it as follows:

   [image]

   this will extract the API [HTTP Status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) and store it into `${responseCode}` variable
2. Amend your While Controller's Condition to use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${__jm__While Controller__idx} < 5 && "${responseCode}" != "200",)}
   ```
3. That's it, assuming above setup your While Controller will break in 2 cases:

   - Response code is `200`
   - API request is executed 5 times

More information: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter)